# Formatting SQL queries in SoapUI JDBC test steps

Tags: groovy, formatting, format, syntax-highlighting, soapui

How can I use [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy) to keep the content of SQL Queries in SoapUI in sync with an external editor?
The solution might look like this:

1. Groovy script to export all the queries of a SoapUI TestSuite or
   TestStep into SQL file(s).
2. Edit and save SQL with external editor.
3. Groovy script to update the queries in SoapUI based on changed
   files.

Initial issues:

- How do I access the query of a teststep? It is not there as a
  porperty, is it?
- Is there a way to run steps 1 and 3 on a project file (XML) instead
  from within a test itself (as setUp/tearDown scripts)?

### Motivation

*SQL Query* input fields of JDBC test steps

1. very small and
2. does not provide any code formatting like indenting, re-wrapping, or upper-casing of SQL keywords  (there is just syntax highlighting).

This is IMHO very cumbersome when writing a query that contains more than a couple of where clauses or even joins.

Side note: If somebody could point me to some functionality (builtin, plugin?) to format the SQL code directly in SoapUI (not pro!), I would gladly pass on groovy scripts.

Comment: I have a rough solution for the latter (export and re-import queries to/from external files using [tag:groovy]) which I will post later on i.e. after a) "your answer" and b) cleaning up the code.

Comment: Product support questions are off-topic for SO. You might want to try https://community.smartbear.com/

Comment: I see your point, @SiKing. But since I suppose that it will result in a Groovy solution (not necessarily my own prototype), I was "automatically" aiming for SO. I will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are my [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy)-scripts that I have implemented in the form of Groovy test steps (they might also be setUp/tearDown scripts, but I prefer separate test steps that are clearly visible and where I can easily toggle their activity):

**Export** all the JDBC/SQL queries of a SoapUI test case into SQL file(s). This might be the final step of the testcase.

```
def testCase = testRunner.testCase
def testSuite = testCase.testSuite
def project = testSuite.project

// Remove .xml extension from filename
String pathToProjectDir = project.path.replaceAll(~/\.\w+$/, '')

File projectDir = new File(pathToProjectDir)
File suiteDir = new File(projectDir, testSuite.name)
File caseDir = new File(suiteDir, testCase.name)

caseDir.mkdirs()
assert caseDir.exists()
assert caseDir.isDirectory()

log.info "Exporting to '${caseDir}'."

testCase.getTestStepsOfType(com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.JdbcRequestTestStep)
    .each{testStep ->
        String filename = "${testStep.name}.sql"
        File file = new File(caseDir, filename)
        file.text = testStep.query
        log.info "'${filename}' written."
    }

log.info "Files written."
```

**Edit** and save SQL with **external editor**.

**Update** the queries in SoapUI based on changed files. Missing or empty files are ignored in order not to break too much in the existing project.

```
def testCase = testRunner.testCase
def testSuite = testCase.testSuite
def project = testSuite.project

// Remove .xml extension from filename
String pathToProjectDir = project.path.replaceAll(~/\.\w+$/, '')

File projectDir = new File(pathToProjectDir)
File suiteDir = new File(projectDir, testSuite.name)
File caseDir = new File(suiteDir, testCase.name)

assert caseDir.exists()
assert caseDir.isDirectory()

log.info "Importing from '${caseDir}'."

testCase.getTestStepsOfType(com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.JdbcRequestTestStep)
    .each{testStep ->
        String filename = "${testStep.name}.sql"
        File file = new File(caseDir, filename)
        if (file.exists()) {
            if (file.text) {
                testStep.query = file.text
                log.info "'${filename}'"
            } else {
                log.warn "Ignoring '${filename}'"
            }
        } else {
                log.warn "'${filename}' does not exist."
        }
    }

log.info "Files imported."
```

The files are placed in the following directory structure:
Starting from the SoapUI project file `path/to/project.xml` itself, a tree is (created and) populated with one SQL file per JDBC test step:
`path/to/project/${name of TestSuite}/${name of TestCase}/${name of TestStep}.sql`